# Postgres - Convert elapse time to HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to calculate elapsed time in format 20:59:59, I have start and end time for my particular record.

Currently, I used to subtract, end date time with start date time to calculate the elapsed time but I am getting the output into this format.

Can we change this to HH:MM:SS format(in this case: 02:23:05).

```
0 years 0 mons 0 days 2 hours 23 mins 5.0 secs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a type `interval`. You can directly cast this into type `time`:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4c63f5e8f23d0b96c7f6fcd2f06531d2)

```
SELECT myresult::time
```

If you want to get string output, you can use datetime formatting using to_char and the 'HH24:MI:SS' pattern:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=58e2a8e7440ad6d9414b3b34d2bfbdaf)

```
SELECT to_char(my_result, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: The first one only works if the interval is smaller than 24 hours.